# A ""'str' object does not support item assignment"" when replacing elements in a list

Tags: python

This is the start of my code of hangman but I get an error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14, in module
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The code is

```
import random
listOfWords = ["example", "potato", "python", "rocks","test", "hangman"]
guessWord = random.choice(listOfWords)
print(guessWord)
splitlist = list(guessWord)
print(splitlist)
dash = "_ " * len(splitlist)
print(dash)
while 0 == 0:
guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
if guess in guessWord:
    for n,i in enumerate(splitlist):
        if i == guess:
            dash[n] = guess
```

Comment: Well, as the error message says, you can't reassign part of a string, like you're trying to do with `dash[n] = guess`.

Comment: Please edit your title to be more descriptive.There are hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow which titles  follow the pattern "Attempt at X failed" or "Tried X and failed".

Comment: thanks for the help @MorganThrapp I know that any suggestions

Comment: do you want dash to be a list? in that case you should use : dash = ["_"]*len(splitlist) . Or if you want dash to be a string, you should know that strings are immutable.

Comment: thank you @Shasha99 I was trying to do a list but had a string:)

Comment: Wrote the answer !!!

Comment: thanks again @Shasha99 :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
dash = "_ " * len(splitlist)
```

will give you a string which will be immutable. Not sure if you need a list instead of string:

```
dash = ["_"] * len(splitlist)
```